# How to edit Azure 'AADSTS50020' error message?

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have drupal website and i added Azure AD login option. If the user who wants to login is not registered on Azure, the following message appears. How can I edit this message as I want? (I want to write a message like contact xxx@domain.com.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to make any changes to this message as it is shown on Microsoft's site when the user is trying to authenticate themselves and not by your application.